# SQL print counts row wise with conditions inside count

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count

I'm new to SQL. I have a table with data as below

```
+-----+-------+
|Name | value |
+-----+-------+
|AAA  |  25   |
|AAA  |  60   |
|BBB  |  40   |
|BBB  |  200  |
|CCC  |  1010 |
|CCC  |  451  |
|CCC  |  45   |
|DDD  |  20   |
+-----+-------+
```

What I'm trying to do is get the below output

```
+-------+-------+
|Name   | COUNT |
+-------+-------+
|AAA    | 2     |
|DDD    | 1     |
|OTHERS | 5     |
+-------+-------+
```

How can I achieve this in SQL??? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression:

```
select
    case when name = 'AAA' then name else 'OTHERS' end new_name,
    count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by case when name = 'AAA' then name else 'OTHERS' end
```

Some databases (namely, MySQL and MariaDB) support reusing column aliases defined in the `select` clause in the `group by` clause, so you can simplify the `group by` clause as:

```
group by new_name
```

Other databases support positional parameters (Postgres and Oracle are two examples):

```
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. Is it still same even If I try with more rows? Have edited my question with more data

Comment: That's a slightly different expression: `case when name in ('AAA', 'DDD') then name else 'OTHERS' end new_name`